# What is happening in the if condition?

Tags: c

One of my friends ask me about this code and I and he are unable to find out, what is happening in the if condition. Can you guys explain how this condition works?

```
int main()
{
   int i;

   if (i = (1, 2, 0))
       printf("Mehrose");
   else
       printf("Hello ");

   printf("%d\n", i);

   return 0;
}
```

The output for this code is Hello 0

Comment: You might want to learn about [the comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator) and how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, formatting as the compiler sees the code we get:

```
int main(void)
{
   int i;
   if(i=(1,2,0))
      printf("Mehrose");
   else 
      printf("Hello");
   printf("%d\n",i);
   return 0;
}
```

The if statement can be broken down:

1. [Comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator) `,` is evaluated first, left-hand side of the operator is discarded. This repeats for each operator:

   `if(i=(1,2,0))`

   `if(i=(2,0))`

   `if(i=0)`
2. The [assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment) `=` assigns a value of `0` to `i`, and returns the right-hand side of the expression:

   `if(0)`
3. Recall that `0` is evaluated as false (is "falsy") and `1` is evaluated as true (is "truthy"). Thus the first condition fails and the second block is executed. "Hello" is printed to the standard output stream, followed by "0".

Answer (score 2):

In the expression,

```
i=(1,2,0)
```

you're using the [comma operator](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.17), which evaluates all its operands and yields the result of its rightmost operand - which is 0 here.
So 0 is assigned to `i`.

So it's equivalent to `if (i = 0)`, which assigns `0` to `i` and yields the value of `i` which is false and thus it prints the string in the else branch.